# QR code reader to extract data

Tags: android, ios, qr-code

i have a sales summary print out and has a QR Code ,
i want to develop an app (IOS and android) that reads the QR code , extract all information,do some calculations,and display in specific form , i tried zxing library but it did not extract all information from the receipt.any tip?

Answer (score 0):

[This library](https://github.com/nisrulz/qreader) is the most popular and easiest of reading QR codes in your Android application.
You should also have a look at the [Wiki](https://github.com/nisrulz/qreader/wiki) section of this library for learning about how to integrate this library into your Android Application and how to use this library.

This is how you can use this library.
1. Add this library to your project by adding following line into your `dependencies` inside **build.gradle(Module: app)** file 
`compile 'com.github.nisrulz:qreader:2.0.0'`
2. Then, after syncing project files, add the `SurfaceView` element provided by this library into your **XML** layout file.

```
<SurfaceView
  android:id="@+id/camera_view"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  />
```

3. Declare the `SurfaceView` & `QREader` inside your Activity's **Java** file & then initialize it inside `onCreate()` method.

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private SurfaceView mySurfaceView;
    private QREader qrEader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Setup SurfaceView
    // -----------------
    mySurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camera_view);

    // Init QREader
    // ------------
    qrEader = new QREader.Builder(this, mySurfaceView, new QRDataListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDetected(final String data) {
        Log.d("QREader", "Value : " + data);
        text.post(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            text.setText(data);
          }
        });
      }
    }).facing(QREader.BACK_CAM)
        .enableAutofocus(true)
        .height(mySurfaceView.getHeight())
        .width(mySurfaceView.getWidth())
        .build();

  }
```

4. Initialize it inside `onResume()`

```
  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Init and Start with SurfaceView
    // -------------------------------
    qrEader.initAndStart(mySurfaceView);
  }
```

There are many more possibilities you can do with this library, so I recommend you to visit the `GitHub` repository and check it out. It's worth a shot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use google vision API to achieve this. I personally used this and found it great. The below code snippets should help you.

Put this below line in the gradle.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
```

Use `BarcodeDetector` and `CameraSource` classes to capture the QR code on real time and decode it.

```
barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {
            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
                final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();

                if (barcodes.size() != 0) {
                    barcodeInfo.post(new Runnable() {    // Use the post method of the TextView
                        public void run() {
                            barcodeInfo.setText(    // Update the TextView
                                    barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue
                            );
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Use a SparseArray to fetch the detections  and the `displayValue` of the elements of this sparse array returns the deocded string.

After extracting the string one can do anything, be it displaying the string or make some calculation out of it etc.